# AWS Lambda in Python intermittently returns NoSuchKey error

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have this python code in a lambda function. This code is invoked when a file is uploaded to S3 bucket. The code throws the NoSuchKey error intermittenly. I have been testing this piece of code using the same file and sometimes I do see the value of the file.

What is it I am doing wrong? I have added the value of the print statements next to those those lines in the code.

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import requests

from io import BytesIO

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # AWS Config Data
    region = os.environ['AWS_REGION_NAME']
    access_key = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS']
    secret_key = os.environ['AWS_SECRET']
    bucket = os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    print(f'Test Obj {obj}') // this is what this line prints out **Test Obj s3.Object(bucket_name='my-bucket', key='FILE_DROP_AT_20231221_1015.txt')**

    data = obj.get()['Body'].read() //the error on cloudwatch points out to this line. Below is the error -
[ERROR] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    data = obj.get()['Body'].read()

    print(f'Data - {data}')


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Here is the error traceback -
[image]

@Minh-Long-Luu
I tried printing obj.get(), the below is what I see -

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '95WE9ZXEVY8QSZDT', 'HostId': 'Ild3WDKtk6mMTRAxAXS0YA6PRUcc2afxyfCB50uRjw5X/iQQxOLU0VGTVckK00jqxcXIa+dCSPE=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'Ild3WDKtk6mMTRAxAXS0YA6PRUcc2afxyfCB50uRjw5X/iQQxOLU0VGTVckK00jqxcXIa+dCSPE=', 'x-amz-request-id': '95WE9ZXEVY8QSZDT', 'date': 'Tue, 26 Dec 2023 02:50:30 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Tue, 26 Dec 2023 02:50:25 GMT', 'etag': '"d9aeb1a75f3c318dc358793b6fe1898f"', 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-length': '425'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 26, 2, 50, 25, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 425, 'ETag': '"d9aeb1a75f3c318dc358793b6fe1898f"', 'ContentType': 'text/plain', 'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256', 'Metadata': {}, 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f7a41c9d120>}
```

I do see the Body property. For a while now I am not seeing this issue. All of a sudden it will throw a NoSuchKey error. This jind of behaviour worries me a lot.

Comment: what's the actual error traceback?

Comment: @NilsWerner I have added the traceback.

Comment: Try printing `obj.get()` results out to see if you have any issue with the response.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu I have added the result of the Obj.get() print statement to the original post.

Comment: I am reading this on chatgpt - Use the head_object method of the S3 client to check if the object exists and is accessible before calling the get_object method4. This can help you avoid unnecessary errors and reduce the latency of your Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not read the key file as you are using `key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']`. You should use `urllib.parse.unquote_plus` to parse the key file. One such example where reading the key normally is:

Let say you upload a file called `test file.txt`. Notice that it has a space in between.

Result without parsing: `test+file.txt`

Result with parsing: `test file.txt`

Secondly, you are reading the s3 bucket name from env. Are you sure that its not getting events from any other bucket?

I would suggest to read the bucket name from the event itself. It will help you reduce errors.

Also, if possible, you can reduce the code further. Check the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). Check the Python implementation of listening to S3 events.

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh, Yes it should receive only items from the specified bucket.